# How to use the `$HOME` environment variable in systemd service files

Tags: linux, systemd, init

I am trying to use the `$HOME` environment variable in the `ExecStart`. I tried many different things like `$HOME` and `${HOME}` but nothing seems to be working

```
ExecStart=${HOME}/bin/some-binary
```

Anyone knows the correct format for this?

Comment: This is not allowed in `ExecStart=`. It must be a full path beginning with a `/`.

Comment: If you want a service to use things in every user's homes, you want a user service, not a system service.

Answer (score 35):

I think this is what you're looking for: https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.unit.html#Specifiers.

Specifically, `%h` should expand to the current user's home dir.

Comment: According to the documentation you have provided, `%h` is the `user home directory`. But, in my case, `ExecStart` still requested the full path so I ended up typing it starting from the root.

Comment: Using `%h` is probably not what you want. I've posted an alternate answer with details.

Answer (score 13):

The full list of supported variables (called "Specifiers") is here: https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.unit.html#Specifiers.

There is no specifier for the home directory of user the service is run as (the one specified by `User=`). There is only one for the user running the service manager.

From the link:

> `%h` is the home directory of the *user running the service manager* instance. In case of the system manager this resolves to "`/root`". Note that this setting is *not* influenced by the `User=` setting configurable in the [Service] section of the service unit.

Comment: Just to be clear, that means if I have a user unit, then `%h` most definitely is what I want to use because it will give me the equivalent of `$HOME`.

Comment: Can confirm. %h resolves to $HOME for --user services.

Answer (score 4):

So, as the absence of practical examples in combination with comments makes a feeling like `%h` doesn't work *(it does actually)*, here's a full example of a service that starts from HOME dir without hardcoding it.

Given:

- a script `~/test.sh`:

  ```bash
  #!/bin/bash
  echo hello
  ```
- a service file `~/.config/systemd/user/test.service`:

  ```ini
  [Unit]
  Description=Test

  [Service]
  Type=oneshot
  ExecStart=%h/test.sh

  [Install]
  WantedBy=multi-user.target
  ```

Then executing a `systemctl --user daemon-reload && systemctl --user start test` will make it start and print `hello` to the journal.

It uses the `%h` specifier mentioned in other answers and is documented as `This is the home directory of the user running the service manager instance. […]`. So unless you'll run your user service as another user, this should work.

Systemd versions tested:

- `systemd 253 (253.1-3-arch)`
- `systemd 237`.

Answer (score 1):

You could use

```
WorkingDirectory=~
```

and set relative paths.